# System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo get passed to my non-error views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We are using MVC 3 and .Net Framework 4.0. We use MVC and Webforms together. For some users, we get System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HeaderModel'.

A regular page looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
    HeaderModel header = new HeaderModel();
    ViewBag.Header = header;
}
<div id="mainAreaContainer">
    ....
</div>
```

At top of each page we create header model object and put it ViewBag.

In layout page we have this:

```
 @Html.Partial("_HeaderPartial", (HeaderModel)ViewBag.Header)
```

Our layout pages does not expect any models.

We get this error on our standard regular views, not on error view.

We have an error page such that error page has a model which inherits from HandleErrorInfo.

As far as I understood, error occurs in regular views, not in error view. We handle unhandled exceptions in global.asax Application_Error part and redirect to error page.
I tried to recreate the error by throwing exceptions from view, controllerbase and some other places but the exception appeared in logs what it is.

Strangely we do not understand real error which generates a HandleErrorInfo in a standard page.